# Is IP Forwarding possible for OpenVPN using pfSense on Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: openvpn, google-compute-engine, pfsense, ip-forwarding

I have a scenario with a pfSense machine (subnet x.x.0.0) on GCP, IPSEC vpn with 10 Site-to-Site is working normal but OpenVPN is not, the struggle resides in routing the packets through OpenVPN network (x.x.10.0) and accessing the LAN on GCP side.

I've already followed tutorials and tried to find a way to fix this, I think IP Forward is the culprit, since it is deactivated by default, but now I'm looking for an alternative to avoid dealing with another machine creation.

Another question is: Is there a way to detach and reattach the External and Internal IPs in GCP??

I know that I can change IP Forward in AWS without killing the machine, the same goes to IP maneuvering, but in GCP I don't know how to do it. (Maybe I can't?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based from your use case, [IP forwarding](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-routes#canipforward) looks to be the most probable solution but you will still need to set it upon the creation of the instance.

You can also reserve, assign or delete IP address on a VM Instances. These options can be found under [VPC Network](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#IP_assign).

You can find more information about IP addresses in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses).

Comment: I see. So I need to do it in gcloud tool, then I can unassign the IP [deleting the instance or deleting the access config.](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#unassign_ip)

And for the IP forwarding case, I'll really need to recreate all the machines. I was used to just disabling it in AWS. Thanks!